# Using clipboard.js with Yii2

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, clipboard.js

I have installed the extension 
`\supplyhog\ClipboardJs\ClipboardJsWidget`
which seemingly working fine.

but I am struggling to make it work in gridview.

as the code for the extension is already using a widget and gridview itself being a widget, so I think that is making the conflict.

The suggested code outside gridview is like this:

```
//Button to copy text
<?= \supplyhog\ClipboardJs\ClipboardJsWidget::widget([
    'text' => "Hello World",
    // 'label' => 'Copy to clipboard',
    // 'htmlOptions' => ['class' => 'btn'],
    // 'tag' => 'button',
]) ?>

//Button to copy text from input id
<?= \supplyhog\ClipboardJs\ClipboardJsWidget::widget([
    'inputId' => "#input-url",
    // 'cut' => false, // Cut the text out of the input instead of copy?
    // 'label' => 'Copy to clipboard',
    // 'htmlOptions' => ['class' => 'btn'],
    // 'tag' => 'button',
]) ?>
```

How I can integrate this in Gridview?

example -

[image: Copy to clipboard]

it just shows like this - the third cell being the result of clipboard code.

[image]

example of text getting hidden

[image]

with the help of @Omer I tried to modified the code like this:

```
.mycopy{
 position:absolute;
right:-10px;
top:-10px;
}
.mycopy .btn{
padding:2px !important;
}




    [
             'attribute' => 'title',
             'format' => 'raw',
             'value' => function($model){
              $button=\supplyhog\ClipboardJs\ClipboardJsWidget::widget([
                  'text' => $model->title,
                  'label' =>'<i class="far fa-copy" aria-hidden="true"></i>',

            ]);
            return "<div style='position:relative'><div style='margin-right:10px;'>".$model->title."</div><div class='mycopy'>".$button."</div></div>";
        }
    ],
```

and the result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: are you trying to populate the button inside the gridview column and want to copy a specific column value from that row when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i understand is that you are trying to populate the button inside the gridview against every row and when clicked, you want a specific text from that row to be copied in the clipboard.

If that is correct then you can do the following, I will create the example code assuming the `user` model being used in the `GridView` and when clicking on the button the `Bio` of the user will be copied to the clipboard.

```
<?=
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',
        'username',
        'active',
        'password',
        'bio',
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{view}{update}{delete}{copy}',
            'buttons' => [
                'copy' => function($url, $model, $key){
                    return \supplyhog\ClipboardJs\ClipboardJsWidget::widget([
                            'text' => $model->bio
                    ]);
                },
            ]
        ],
    ],
]);
?>
```

Note: You can change the `$model->description` to any column name you are trying to copy `'text' => $model->description`.

And if you are planning to show it inside the `DataColumn` rather than the `ActionColumn` you can use the following piece of code, it will show the column text and a button under it to copy the text to the clipoard.

```
[
    'attribute' => 'bio',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function($model){
        $button=\supplyhog\ClipboardJs\ClipboardJsWidget::widget([
                    'text' => $model->bio,
        ]);
        return $model->bio."<br/>".$button;
    }
],
```

#### Update

To replicate the same css as mentioned in your image you should do the following

Add this css on top of your view

```
$css = <<< CSS
.clip-input-group{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
.input-group-button {
    width: 14%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    float: left;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.input-group-button i{
    font-size:12px;
}
.clip-input{
   width: 85%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-right-color: transparent;
}
CSS;
$this->registerCss($css);
```

Then change your column definition to the following, I am using the fontawesome clipboard icon instead of using the image,

Note: I am not a css expert but managed to create the same, if some one can suggest better classes I am open to suggestions

```
[
    'attribute' => 'bio',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function ($model) {
            $button = \supplyhog\ClipboardJs\ClipboardJsWidget::widget([
                'text' => $model->bio,
                'label' => '<i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                'htmlOptions' => ['class' => ''],
                'tag' => 'a',
            ]);
            $text = $model->bio;
            $html = <<< HTML
            <div class="clip-input-group">
                <input type="text" disabled value="{$text}" class="clip-input">
                <span class="input-group-button">
                    $button
                </span>
            </div>
HTML;

            return $html;
        },
],
```

Comment: No, Omar I just want to have it enabled for just a specific cell, not the entire row. so I want the copy button inside the cell, which I want to copy. okay you have given the example for that as well. let me try.

Comment: @Joshi you can use the last part where i showed you how to use it in the DataColumn and pass the relevant column in the `text` option, and it does not copy the whole row only the cell /field

Comment: the answer above does not copy the entire row by the way

Comment: Hi Omar I tried the last part. It is working fine, but the column is showing only "copy to Clipboard" not the actual text of the column, though it is copying it correctly. what could be the reason for this?

Comment: @Joshi if you want to show the actual column text inside the button , the use the `'label'=>$model->column_name`

Comment: should I replace the part - `'label' => 'Copy to clipboard'`

Comment: @Joshi yes thats what i am talking about

Comment: Sorry Omar, but that removes the text 'Copy to Clipboard'. I want the copy button as well as the text.

Comment: @Joshi you want the button along with the text in the column?

Comment: @Joshi see the last code block again , i hope that is what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks Omer, it's working. I think I will manage it. but I wanted the copy button something like in the example I have just updated in the question.

Comment: @Joshi yes we can do that too with a bit of css involved, give me a few mins i will update shortly

Comment: Thanks. So nice of you Omer. This is the link from where I added the example, if you want to see the css underneath. - https://clipboardjs.com/

Comment: Hi Omer - It's not working in my setup with the update code. Though I got another ext. link which supposedly already formatted with a copy button in the end - not exactly like the example I have given, but looks better.
but when implementing that in the same line as per your code, it just copies the first cell, irrespective of where you click the button. the link is - https://github.com/eddmash/yii2-clipboard

Comment: @Joshi well i used the one previously mentioned in your question, and itworks great i just tested

Comment: I don't know Omer - but I posted the result I am getting in the question.

Comment: if I am adding text `copy` inside the `i` tag like `<i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true">copy</i>` then text copy is showing it works.
so it looks like it is not able to located fa fa icon.

Comment: @Joshi you need to include the fontawesome style sheet look [here](https://fontawesome.com/start) how to include

Comment: Hi Omer, thanks. that resolved the issue of having icons. but what I can see is that the actual contents are not shown in full, part of of gets hidden in the gridcell. any specific reason for this?

Comment: well there is a limit for the text to be displayed inside the cell and the input i am not sure what you are actually referring to, if you can show an image of what you are seeing currently then i might be able to help @Joshi

Comment: Hi, Omer I have added the image, how I am getting it.

Comment: HI Omer I modified the code from your first example and it is working fine now. I have posted the code I have updated. Thank you so much for your help.